# Проблемы с выводом данных из бд через php

Tags: php, mysql

Мне надо вывести все столбцы из бд, но если столбец повторяется то его не выводить.
Например:

```
У меня таблица users, в ней 3 записи
id|first_name|last_name
0|Данил|Такой-то
1|Данил|Такой-то
2|Данил2|Такой-то 2
То выведет так:

id:0
Имя:Данил
Фамилия:Такой-то
---------------
id:2
Имя:Данил2
Фамилия:Такой-то 2
```

Просто как так вывести?
php 7.1.5 mysql
Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/mysql-distinct.html . Ну а дальше через пхп результаты запроса выводи

Comment: В базе id не должен начинать с 0. Приши свой sql запрос чтобы точно сказатью видимо в запросе у тебя есть group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта чтобы удалить дубликаты из выборки.

**Первый способ**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, first_name, last_name FROM users ORDER BY id
```

**Второй способ**

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users GROUP BY id, last_name, first_name
```